# Akka directive fileUpload copies the entire input entity file into memory?

Tags: file-upload, akka, akka-stream

Does Akka directive "fileUpload" copies the entire input entity file into memory?  Is there a way to do multipart upload of large file as 1 GB without consuming 1 GB of memory?

```
      val uploadFile = File.createTempFile("uploadFile", ".txt")
      extractRequestContext { ctx =>
        implicit val materializer = ctx.materializer
        implicit val ec = ctx.executionContext

        fileUpload("csv") {
          case (metadata, byteSource) =>
            val sumF = byteSource.runFold(ByteString.empty) { case (acc, i) => acc ++ i }.map(s => s.utf8String)

            onSuccess(sumF) { sum =>
              Files.write(Paths.get(uploadFile.getAbsolutePath), sum.toString.getBytes)
              logger.info(StatusCodes.OK + "Successfully completed fileUpload ")
              complete(s"Successfully completed fileUpload") }}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach gathers the entire file into memory. To avoid doing that, stream the file to disk with a [`sink`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.3/akka/stream/scaladsl/FileIO$.html#toPath(f:java.nio.file.Path,options:Set[java.nio.file.OpenOption]):akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink[akka.util.ByteString,scala.concurrent.Future[akka.stream.IOResult]]):

```scala
val uploadFile = File.createTempFile("uploadFile", ".txt")

extractRequestContext { ctx =>
  implicit val materializer = ctx.materializer
  implicit val ec = ctx.executionContext

  fileUpload("csv") {
    case (metadata, byteSource) =>
      val result =
        byteSource.via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 10000))
                  .runWith(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(uploadFile.getAbsolutePath)))

      onSuccess(result) { res =>
        logger.info(StatusCodes.OK + "Successfully completed fileUpload ")
        complete(s"Successfully completed fileUpload")
      }
  }
}
```

You might need to adjust [`akka.http.server.parsing.max-content-length`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.9/scala/http/common/http-model.html#1) or the [`maximumFrameLength`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.3/akka/stream/scaladsl/Framing$.html#delimiter(delimiter:akka.util.ByteString,maximumFrameLength:Int,allowTruncation:Boolean):akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[akka.util.ByteString,akka.util.ByteString,akka.NotUsed]) in the delimiter (10000 in the above example).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, problem was with runFold,  with runWith resolved the problem.

```
      extractDataBytes { bytes =>

                  val path = Files.createTempFile(ATTACHMENT_NAME + "_" + "upload", "dat")

                  val futureWriteResult: Future[IOResult] = bytes.runWith(FileIO.toPath(path))


                  onSuccess(futureWriteResult) {
                    case IOResult(count, Success(Done)) => UploadContent(path, parent, tenant, ATTACHMENT_NAME, async).execute()
                    case IOResult(_, Failure(ex)) => throw ex
                  }
              }
```